# How can I format (lint, fix, style) an entire repo's history?

Tags: git, lint

I've become the sole developer on an old C++ repo that never had style rules.

I often have to analyze history, compare branches, etc, and would like to do this without ever having to deal with the visual pollution of cosmetic changes. I'd also like to enforce a consistent code style.

I'm contemplating modifying the entire repo's history so that my chosen linter/formatter rules are applied for every single commit from beginning to end.

How would I do this?

Concrete goals:

1. For every single commit, apply linter fixes to all added/modified files that are under src/. But, do not fix code in src/3rdparty or the arbitrary file ./src/subdir/exceptionexample.
2. Insert the same static files .editorconfig and .linterconfig in the very first commit, so that they're there in every single commit.

Notes:

- The repo has several release branches, all supported for the foreseeable future. So I can't just fix the tip of master and say "the problem will fix itself over time".
- I'm the only person working on this repo, so I wouldn't be breaking anything by rewriting history

Answer (score 0):

You will build an *entirely new repository* from the result.  You won't be able to mix the old repository with the new one:

> I'm the only person working on this repo, so I wouldn't be breaking anything by rewriting history ...

The main problem is that if someone ever updates the *old* repository, you'll have some headaches.  (Fortunately you can reformat just their *new* commits, putting the reformatted new commits into your new repository—but you'll need some way to identify which ones are new on their side.)

Now, as to the mechanics of doing this:

> 1. For every single commit, apply linter fixes to all added/modified files that are under `src/`. But, do not fix code in `src/3rdparty` or the arbitrary file `./src/subdir/exceptionexample`.
> 2. Insert the same static files `.editorconfig` and `.linterconfig` in the very first commit, so that they're there in every single commit.

That first part is up to your linter.  Figure out how to make it do this.

The second part is straightforward.  Just copy the files into place each time.  The reason is simple: a Git repository is a collection of commits.  Each commit is a *full and complete snapshot of every file* (that Git knew about at the time), i.e., an archive, as if made by `tar` or `rar` or `winzip` or whatever.  It just *also* has some added *metadata* that tells who made the commit, when, and so on.

Your repository-rebuilder software will operate by:

1. For each commit, extract the snapshot (into a temporary directory).  Note that this is a just whole snapshot, extracted: it has nothing to do with any previous snapshot.  There are no *changes* involved.  It's just a whole directory full of files-and-subdirectories.
2. Run your chosen command(s) in the temporary directory.
3. Use the resulting files, exactly as produced by your commands, to make the new snapshot.

The new snapshot will have the same metadata as the original snapshot, minus any original GPG or PGP signatures (these cannot be preserved because the code is presumably different now).  You can, if you wish, make some changes to the metadata as well, e.g., to fix up the email addresses or whatever—after all, you're making *all new commits*, so all parts of the original commit are available to be modified however you like.

Let's call process of extracting, adjusting (or "filtering"), and making-as-new each original-to-new commit, the process of *filtering* a repository.  The obvious name for this command is therefore `git filter-repo`.

The *parent commit(s)* of each new commit will be the new hash IDs of the results of filtering each original parent commit.  That is, suppose the original repository were the rather simple:

```
     C--D
    /    \
A--B      G--H   <-- main
    \    /
     E--F
```

The result of filtering this branch named `main` would be:

```
     C'-D'
    /    \
A'-B'     G'-H'  <-- main
    \    /
     E'-F'
```

where the `'` ("prime") suffixes represent the fact that each of these *new* commits `A'` through `H'` has a new, random-looking hash ID, with no obvious relationship to the hash IDs of the original commits `A` through `H`.  However, just as the original `A` commit has *no* parent, the new `A'` commit has *no* parent; just as the original `B` commit has commit `A` as its parent, the new `B'` has `A'` as its parent; and so on.

The name `main` in the original repository referred to commit `H`.  The name `main` in the replacement repository refers to commit `H'`.

[The `git filter-repo` command](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) is very new and is not actually included in Git distributions yet.  If you choose to use that one, read its documentation.  If you want to use the command that *does* come with Git, even though it's technically deprecated, what you will use is `git filter-branch` with the `--tree-filter` option:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter ... --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Replace the `...` part with a shell command that can be `eval`-ed—the name of an executable script will do—and note that this executable script will be run in some temporary directory that is **not a Git repository** and has a somewhat unpredictable path.  You will want to:

- copy the two dot-files from some absolute path to the current directory; then
- run your linter/reformatter on all files except for any files you don't want reformatted, all of which live in the current directory and its subdirectories.

The resulting files—if any; if you remove any files, those files will be *gone*; if you add any files, those files will be *included*—will make up the *new snapshot*.

When `git filter-branch` is done, the old repository is (semi-)destroyed and the new one has taken its place.  So run it on a clone, not the original; consider using `git clone --mirror` to make a clone that has all branches.

The `git filter-branch` command is slow.  The `--tree-filter` mode is *extremely* slow.  You can speed it up somewhat using the `-d` option: point this to an in-memory (rather than on-disk) file system, to make it put all the temporary files there.  The new filter-repo command is *much faster*, though I have not used it.